# Populate BindProperty Collections when jQuery Datatables Changes Row Orders

Tags: c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller, datatables

When populating a controller's BindProperty Model Collection in MVC, it seems I can only add to a return array when the index is in order.

Here is working code I've used in several applications:

**Controller  code:**

The bind property that gets populated:

```
[BindProperty]
public EditRatesModel EditModel { get; set; }
```

The Model above:

```
public class EditRatesModel
    {
        public EditRateType EditRateType { get; set; }
        public List<PayCode> PayCodes { get; set; } <--This works as array or List
        ...
```

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToActionResult EditFields()
{
     EditModel.PayCodes  <-- This object gets populated on form submit
```

**The View Code:**

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="EditFields" method="post" id="rateForm">
     <table id="editTable" style="width: 100%; display: none" class="display" cursor="pointer">
     <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Type</th>
               <th>Description</th>
               <th>Abbreviation</th>
               <th>Active</th>
           </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="font-size: .8em">

    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.PayCodes.Count(); i++)
    {
         <tr>
             <td>
                  <select class="hideFormBox pointerTransform" name="EditModel.PayCodes[@i].PayCodeType" id="EditModel.PayCodes[@i].PayCodeType">
              @if (@Model.PayCodes[i].PayCodeType.Equals("Credit"))
              {
                  <option selected value="Credit">Credit</option>
                  <option value="Debit">Debit</option>
              }
              else
              {
                  <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
                  <option selected value="Debit">Debit</option>
              }
                  </select>
             </td>
             <td>
                  <textarea class="hideFormBox" name="EditModel.PayCodes[@i].PayCodeDesc" id="EditModel.PayCodes[@i].PayCodeDesc" rows="1" required>@Model.PayCodes[i].PayCodeDesc</textarea>
            </td>
             ...


            <input type="hidden" name="EditModel.PayCodes[@i].PayCodeKey" id="EditModel.PayCodes[@i].PayCodeKey" value="@Model.PayCodes[i].PayCodeKey" />
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="EditModel.EditRateType" id="EditModel.EditRateType" value="@EditRateType.PayCode" />
</form>

@section ChartScript
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#editTable').show();
            $('#editTable').DataTable({
                    searching: false,
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [],
                }
            );
        });

    </script>
}
```

My issue comes about when a user sorts or filters in jQuery Datatables.

**Example of the index issue:**

```
If I had three objects from db with index 0, 1, 2 - 
If the user sorts by reverse order: 2, 1, 0 = 1 item (index 0)
If the user goes to the second page: 10, 11, 12.. = 0 items (no 0)
If the user sorts filters something: 0, 10 = 1 item
```

I could turn off sorting, but this wouldn't solve the paging issue. 
To fix paging, id have to either load mvc with ajax, or load a new view for say 10 at a time.

**My question:**
There has to be a way a better way to do this without using the @HTML editor or paging in the controller? 
Is there perhaps a js or jquery solution that lets me populate the dumb hard coded objects out of order?

As a last result, I suppose I could AJAX in, AJAX out? I'm not sure how to do the latter given the editing approach above though.

*My apologies for the long winded and probably unconventional question. My frontend experience is limited.*